# "Helped test" or "helped testing"

Tags: verbs, conjugations

I'm trying to fill in a job application form and came across a problem. in one of the project descriptions I was in the process of testing something. but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to write it down.

"I helped test prototypes"

or

"I helped testing prototypes"

which one is the correct one or are both correct or neither?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Help* in that sense normally takes an infinitive clause, with or without "to", so *I helped [to] test prototypes*. It does not normally take an "-ing" clause, so your second choice, though understandable, is not idiomatic.

There is a different meaning of *help*, usually in the negative *can't/couldn't help* which does take an "-ing" clause.

The [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/help#Verb) gives "usage notes" which explain this.

Answer (score 1):

> I helped (to) test prototypes.

> I helped in testing prototypes.

Both the above sentences indicate that you are involved in the process of helping someone to test the prototypes created. As said by Colin in their answer, *help* usually goes in its infinitive form. However, if you want to use gerund form in your sentence, you may consider using the preposition *in*.